# Could CDN be faster way to load resources?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, cdn

I was setting up the admin panel for a blog today, and I decided just to use the CDN bootstrap link rather than keeping the files local on the server since this was just some initial testing. I figured that I would add the files to the server later in order to speed it up, but that's when I had a thought.

This particular server is a Bluehost shared server and is inexplicably slow. Could it actually be faster if I used the CDN? And would it be noticeable?

I know StackOverflow likes questions to be specific, so let's use Bootstrap's CDN in this particular scenario since it is a popular framework.

Comment: Why don't you measure the performance? Chrome, for instance, has a tool that will show you how long each sub-document takes to load on a page.

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: See [this page](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/) to get started.

Comment: You can see for yourself if you open your Network tab in Chrome's developer console and refresh the page. Be sure to clear your cache though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could it actually be faster if I used the CDN?

Yes. CDNs are a good option not only because they are usually very fast servers, but also because when you use a popular CDN, the sources you need (e.g. boostrap, jQuery) may have already been downloaded by the user at another site and, as such, will hit the browser's cache - and then load as fast as it possibly could.

> And would it be noticeable?

This depends on how slow the current server is in relation to the CDN.

Google DevTools have a useful tool to this. They have a whole section dedicated to that: **[Get Started with Analyzing Network Performance in Chrome DevTools](https://web.archive.org/web/20190130185512/https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/)**. It includes guided to tools that assist you in emulating connections and devices, analyzing requests (find out which scripts are taking longer to load or which stylesheets are affecting rendering), and more.

[image: x]
<sub>(source: [google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/imgs/get-started-waterfall.png))</sub>

In the example above you can see how much time a resource actually took to download. That screen is available at Chrome (<kbd>Command+Option+I</kbd> [Mac] or <kbd>Control+Shift+I</kbd> [Windows, Linux]).

Answer (score 1):

CDN's help in two ways,

1> the server closest to the user is normally not subject to the world wide wait effect of network traffic.

2> there is also a benefit to a common location because the resource may be cached on the browser from a different website. **Same type of effect if you make one CSS file for your entire site, the user only downloadd it once and caches it** ... CDN takes this across domains. This makes the first speed test closer to the refreshed speed test because the resource was in cache before they came to your site.

Twitter for example uses bootstrap but sadly its implementation is heavy and may conflict with your usage. Needless to say the benefit of using the twitter bootstrap is anybody who uses twitter will have zero wait time to load the resource when they hit your page.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />
    <script 
src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If you promote your site through twitter it is a consideration though, because those visitors will see better performance. **As if bootstrap was a native feature of the browser.**

Bootstrap suggests using this CDN.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I would stay with their recommendation of CDN unless there is a reason not to. It makes everybody's website faster.

If you use a CDN you pay for as a resource for a public lib you lose the 2nd benefit.

3> It is also possible that the ISP may cache these common resource URLS, shorting the distance to the user even more. They do this to save bandwidth, which costs them money.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: It will always be faster loading your assets locally because you won't depend on the network or the CDN server. The slower your server is, it will probably be faster than downloading the library over the network.

Comment: "It will always be faster loading your assets locally" - the OP was talking about JavaScript resources being local to the *server*, so there will be a network dependency.

Comment: Ken, on that note: browsers limit connects to a single server to two connects. Most browsers do better with up to six connects downloading at the same time. The trade off is the DNS request speed.

Answer (score -1):

No. Never. Your production code should be all in one file and [minified](https://javascript-minifier.com/).

The issue is initiating an HTTP request is an expensive thing, timewise. Each `<script>`kickstarts another HTTP session.

For development purposes, it doesn't matter; but in production it's all crammed in a single serve minified package. For example see Google.com's web source code and search for `<script src=` and notice there are 0 occurrences.